# unable to download Tello SDK for IOS

Tags: ios

Anyone knows how to download the Tello sdk for iOS. I have visited the link https://www.ryzerobotics.com/tello, but it is not useful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked to the supplier of the software themselves and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official SDK to download for the Tello. You can find the instructions at [this link](https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf) which provides details of sending UDP packets over a network connection to the drone. You can use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) found on GitHub to help you create the connection to the socket and then pass the commands as ASCII data to the Tello.

Here is some sample code to get you going (which I wrote earlier today on my own [website](https://www.devfright.com/connecting-to-the-dji-ryze-tello-sdk-with-ios-and-swift-tutorial/)):

```
var socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket()
let sendHost = "192.168.10.1"
let sendPort: UInt16 = 8889
let statePort: UInt16 = 8890
```

First, create the socket, a String with the Tello IP, and a couple of constants holding the port numbers (8889 is used to send commands to, and also receives responses back such as "OK" if the command was successful. 8890 is used for receiving telemetry from the drone multiple times per second.

This will send the initial "command" command to the Tello:

```
// Set the delegate and dispatch queue
socket.setDelegate(self)
socket.setDelegateQueue(DispatchQueue.main)

// Send the "command" command to the socket.
do {
    try socket.bind(toPort: sendPort)
    try socket.enableBroadcast(true)
    try socket.beginReceiving()
    socket.send("command".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
                toHost: sendHost,
                port: sendPort,
                withTimeout: 0,
                tag: 0)
} catch {
    print("Command command sent.")
}
```

You need to make sure that the class conforms to GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate.

Implement the delegate method which receives data from the Tello.

```
func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {
let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
if (sock.localPort() == sendPort) {
    print(dataString)
}

if (sock.localPort() == statePort) {
    var telloStateDictionary = [String:Double]()
    let stateArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: ";")

    for itemState in stateArray! {
        let keyValueArray = itemState.components(separatedBy: ":")
        if (keyValueArray.count == 2) {
            telloStateDictionary[keyValueArray[0]] = Double(keyValueArray[1])
        }
    }
    print(telloStateDictionary)
}
```

}

Set up port 8890 for listening to the telemetry:

```
let receiveSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    do {
        try receiveSocket.bind(toPort: statePort)
    } catch {
        print("Bind Problem")
    }

    do {
        try receiveSocket.beginReceiving()
    } catch {
        print("Receiving Problem")
    }
```

Run the app. Assuming you have manually connected to the Tello (like you would if you were controlling it with the Tello app), you should begin getting information back from the Tello.

To send more commands to it, such as "takeoff" or "cw 360", you can do something such as:

```
func sendCommand(command: String) {
    let message = command.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    socket.send(message!, toHost: sendHost, port: sendPort, withTimeout: 2, tag: 0)
}
```

Pass in the command as a string, and this will send it to the Tello.

Comment: Have you implemented the video streaming? I am able to push "streamon" command to UDP port and able to listen the data from port 11111. But I am getting issue while decoding it (H264).

Comment: I haven't yet, but will be looking at it this week.